# Abrir modal de entrada

Tags: modal

Quiero abrir el modal mientras carga la pagina

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery('#mymodal').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Actualmente se abre con un boton, pero no quiero ese boton, quiero que se abra solo una vez al inicio de la pagina

Answer (score 4):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

He utilizado un simple codigo para que cuando el documento este listo el modal se muestre con `jQuery(selector).modal('show')`.

como ves es posible abrirlo directamente desde el código, ademas hay mas opciones aquí te dejo la documentación [Modal Options Via Js](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/modal/)

**Edit**:

Como comentaste que deseas que se oculte automaticamente luego de 5 segundos debes agregar el siguiente código que se ejecutara luego de un intervalo de 5000 milisegundos es decir 5 segundos.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  jQuery("#mymodal").fadeOut(); 
}, 5000);
```

Comment: podrias explicar un poco la respuesta? no se entiende que cambiaste. mira por favor [answer]

Comment: pero debe cerrarse en 5 segundos, como hago eso

Comment: Solo agrega esta función `setTimeout(function(){   $("#myModal").hide();},5000);` con esto tu modal se cierra a los 5 segundos.

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por la sugerencia

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes una solución elegante:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mymodal").modal("show");

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#mymodal").fadeOut();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: recuerda revisar [answer] pues no es solo poner el código y ya, además debes explicarlo para que esta respuesta le sea útil no solo a quien pregunta si no al resto de usuarios que la consulten

Comment: por otro lado esta mal visto que se use la zona de respuestas para mandar saludos o felicitaciones, eso no es relevante